# Make SVN working copy to work on localhost

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, localhost

I am new to SVN. Need help from you guys.

I have a link to an online SVN repository.

I created a folder (wcf) and take "Checkout" from that repository. All files are copied into my folder (wcf). As far as I understands, this folder (wcf) is now a Working Copy of that repository.

Can anyone tell me how I can access this working copy (wcf) on my localhost?

I tried this: localhost/wcf/

but it does nothing.

I am working in PHP.

Please, help!

Regards!

Comment: try with virtual host for your wcf project, may be there is a code which works with virtual host

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing the working copy on my localhost"? A working copy is just a bunch of directories and files on your own disk, which you can work with. Are you asking how to deploy a PHP project in a web server? If so, it would depend on which project, and which web server.

Comment: @JBNizet, no I am not asking how to deploy PHP project. I just want to know how to access my working copy locally.

Comment: Well, you access it like you access any other file on your disk: using the file explorer, an editor to edit the PHP files, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanx! You are right. It will be accessible like any other project. Actually, in my case my working copy was a Magento instance. So, I have to change database path, username, password, and database name in Magento's configuration file and also change base URL in Magento's Database. I learned it the hard way. Anyhow, problem is solved.

Comment: So add an answer, and accept that answer later, so that others don't look at your (unanswered) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. By default, we don't have to change anything. A working copy is accessible just like any other project on localhost. In my case, I was using Magento. If our working copy connects to a database and connecting to that database from localhost is not possible then we have to create a new database with similar schema on our localhost. Change database path in our working copy's configuration file and everything will be working.

All I did was change database path in local.xml & change base URL in Magento's database (table: core_config_data).

Anyhow, thanx everyone!

Regards!